# Can I put a list in a struct?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, struct

I am trying to use a list as part of a struct due to the fact our products come in several colors.  Is this some thing I can do or should i just use an array?  Either way i have not found any examples on the web.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>  
#include<string>  
#include<sstream>  
#include<cctype> 
#include<list>

using namespace std;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Constances
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#define N_PRODUCT 3

struct Brand_t {
int Model_Num;
string Product_Name;
list<string> Colors;
} brands [N_COLOR];

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Functions
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


int main()
{
string mystr;
int n;

for (n=0; n < N_PRODUCT; n++)
{
    cout << "Enter Model Number: ";
    std::getline (cin,mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> brands[n].model_Num,4;
    cout << "Enter Product Name: ";
    getline(cin,classrooms[n].Product_Name);
    list<string>::iterator it;
    Students.push_back ("Red");
    Students.push_back ("Yellow");
    Students.push_back ("Blue");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: In c++ a struct is a class, with an implied public: at the top. But for code readability only use if for data, with all members public. I some times add a constructor and maybe a destructor, but no other methods. But if you are explicit about access, then the language does not care.

Comment: list vs. array is a very weird tradeoff. vector vs. array, sure, but lists have entirely different performance characteristics; if you really need a list, and can't use std::list for some reason (which is very rare), you'd probably substitute a C-style linked list, not a C-style array.

Comment: I think I figured out what may be wrong where it says Students its suppose to be Colors.  and when i put this together I took from diffrent examples, but I think the refrence should be brands[n].Colors.push_back ("Red");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. Thanks to the RAII, the `list` object will be automatically initialized and freed based on the lifetime of your struct. Take note that even thought this is not the case in other programming languages such as Object Pascal, the `struct` and `class` are effectively the same thing in C++, the only difference being default visibility of member methods and variables, as other answers have noted.

You can not put non-[PODS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) objects into unions though.

I suggest you use a `std::vector` or a `std::array` instead of a C-style array. A `std::vector` would probably be most useful if your array is supposed to be of dynamic size. If you use plain `new` or even `malloc()`, then your objects will NOT be automatically freed (not even initialized with `malloc()`)

Comment: Well, an array would be cleaned up automatically as well unless you allocated it dynamically.

Comment: Note: You *can* (in C++11) put non-PODs into unions, even if I would not recommend doing it (you have to manually control the lifetime of the object, call the constructor and destructor as needed to change the active member in the union... painful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is no reason not to.  The only differences between a `struct` and a `class` in C++ are

A) `struct` members are public by default, and

B) `struct` inheritance is public by default (i.e., `struct A : B` is equivalent to `class A : public B` where `B` is a `class`.)

Comment: +1 for pointing out the second difference, I wasn't aware of that one.

Answer (score 1):

Using a list, or any object, inside of a struct is perfectly acceptable as long as the object has or supports a default constructor.

The default constructor is required because when a struct variable is first declared, it is also initialized. Any object inside of it will also be initialized by calling the default constructor.

Comment: Also known as RAII. Good answer though, and welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: If the struct is given a constructor with an initializer list, it can contain objects that are not default cosntructable.

Comment: This is incorrect on two accounts: `struct` is equivalent to `class` but has a default access specifier of `public`, so anything that can be done in a `class` can be done in a `struct`. Even considering only aggregates (i.e. no constructors), you can store objects that don't have a default constructor. This will force all uses of your type to use *aggregate-initialization*, but it can be done.

Comment: @Drise: I am not sure what you mean by that comment, where is the RAII concept mentioned in this answer? RAII is quite unrelated to the answer.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Unless I'm horribly mistaken, "...struct variable is first declared, it is also initialized." Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Drise: That is not what RAII is about, RAII is about resource management, where the acquisition of the resource is to be considered initialization of the object (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization) and more importantly, resources are released in the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with having an instance of a class as a member of a struct in C++, UNLESS you're relying on C++ treating instance of the struct as POD (plain old data) objects. (Like with bit-wise copying, etc.

Comment: and you should _never assume_ an object is a POD.  Always check at compile-time.